# Shortcut of a Robot Framework keyword to show the method definition

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

Is there any shortcut in pycharm to navigate from a Keyword (Robot Framework) to its python definition method.
I use Intellibot as a plugin in Pycharm.
Thanks for help.

Comment: I tried CTRL+B but it is not working

Comment: ctrl+alt+g works for me. There's no true answer since you can configure pycharm to suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just press Ctrl key and do a mouse click on the keyword. It will allow you to navigate to the definition.